# "Not supported by BasicDataSource" cloudfoundry tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, cloud-foundry

I have experience with developing application using Spring JPA and Hibernate.
I set up my datasource as described in 
http://blog.springsource.org/2011/11/04/using-cloud-foundry-services-with-spring-part-2-auto-reconfiguration/ with using xml tag "`<cloud:data-source ...`"

And when i deploy my application i get this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:427)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy19.getRecipeList(Unknown Source)
    com.exigen.common.service.RecipeServiceImpl.getRecipeList(RecipeServiceImpl.java:14)
    com.exigen.common.web.HelloController.index(HelloController.java:25)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1062)
    org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:68)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:59)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy19.getRecipeList(Unknown Source)
    com.exigen.common.service.RecipeServiceImpl.getRecipeList(RecipeServiceImpl.java:14)
    com.exigen.common.web.HelloController.index(HelloController.java:25)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I tried to use google to solve my problem and get this post as searching result:

[https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF28/Fix+'Not+supported+by+BasicDataSource'+Setup+or+Startup+Error](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF28/Fix+%27Not+supported+by+BasicDataSource%27+Setup+or+Startup+Error)

So it seems that i need additional configuration on cloud tomcat but i don't have access to it.

May be i missed something. Could you please advice some solution and working code example?

P.S. I know about jdbc template, actually it is not good solution because my task is practice with JPA.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one type of RDBMS service in your application, then you wont even need to use the `<cloud>` namespace. If you look at the following docs page: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html
and look at the "**Relational Database (MySQL and vFabric Postgres)**", you can see how auto-reconfiguration works.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also work for me not related to the cloud. I move my dataSource to Tomcat instead of manully creating it in application and get same error. Removing hibernate.connection.username and hibernate.connection.password from properties help to solve this issue as discribed here:

[Fix 'Not supported by BasicDataSource' Setup or Startup Error](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF28/Fix+'Not+supported+by+BasicDataSource'+Setup+or+Startup+Error)

Answer (score 0):

add packagesToScan into your EntityManagerFactory configuration

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.domain" />
```